# Can't connect via RDP to Windows 2008 R2 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-services

I just installed a Windows 2008 Standard R2 server with RDS.  Whenever I attempt to connect to the server via RDP from a Windows 2003 server, I get the following error.

[image]

I am however able to connect from a Windows 7 desktop and using a Linux RDP client.

Anyone know why I'm getting this error and how to resolve the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a Server Fault question, but none the less my guess is the server has the following setting:

[image: Setting]

Maybe your Linux RDP client doesn't support this functionality?

If not, check your Firewall, it needs to look like this:

[image: Firewall]

Comment: Actually, its on the middle option. Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop.  I didn't start having the problem until RDS was installed.

Comment: The firewall is completely disabled.

Comment: You might want to turn that on, but is the `Allow Remote Connections` checkbox grayed out and ticked or grayed out and not ticked?

Comment: There you go, you need to ask somebody with Admin rights to tick it!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16635/discussion-between-craig-efrein-and-jmk)